# Rails: How do I check if a column has a value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

How can I accomplish this?

```
<% for agent in @broker.agents %>
  ...
  <% if agent.cell %><span class="cell-number">Cell: <%= agent.cell %></span><% end %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

I want to test to see if the agent has a cell number, and if so, display what's inside the conditional.  What I have currently doesn't seem to work; it just displays "Cell: ".

Thoughts?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is what you asked for:

```
<% for agent in @broker.agents %>
  <% unless agent.cell.blank? %>
    <span class="cell-number">Cell: <%= agent.cell %></span>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The cell? method works whether cell is nil or an empty string.  Rails adds similar functions for all ActiveRecord attributes.  This will look a little nicer:

```
<% for agent in @broker.agents %>
  <span class="cell-number">
    Cell: <%= agent.cell? ? "none given" : agent.cell %>
  </span>
<% end %>
```

The question mark and colon form a quick "if ? then : else" statement.  There are two question marks in the code above because one is part of the method name cell? and the other is a part of the if/then/else construction.

Comment: You can simplify this by doing `<%= agent.cell || "none given" %>`

Answer (score 13):

I am giving a very detailed answer to this Question "**How do I check if a column has a value?**".

First of all, it is important to note that an attribute can have four kinds of values in it.

1. **nil** value i.e "nil" stored in the database
2. **empty** value i.e "" an empty string with **no spaces**
3. **empty** string **with spaces** " ".
4. value present in database i.e a **non-empty string**.

Here is the detail behavior of all the present methods(Ruby 2.2.2) that could be used in this case.

**First Method:** `.empty?`

1. For **nil** value => Throws an exception

   ```
   2.2.2 :037 > object.attribute
   => nil
   2.2.2 :025 > object.attribute.empty?
   NoMethodError: undefined method `empty?' for nil:NilClass
   ```
2. For **empty** value i.e "" an empty string with **no spaces**

   ```
   2.2.2 :037 > object.attribute
   => ""
   2.2.2 :025 > object.attribute.empty?
   true
   ```
3. **empty** string **with spaces** " ".

   ```
   2.2.2 :041 > object.attribute
   => " " 
   2.2.2 :042 > object.attribute.empty?
   => false
   ```
4. value present in database i.e a **non-empty string**.

   ```
   2.2.2 :045 > object.attribute
    => "some value" 
   2.2.2 :046 > object.attribute.empty?
    => false
   ```

**Second Method:** `.nil?`

1. **nil** value i.e "nil" stored in the database

   ```
   2.2.2 :049 > object.attribute
    => nil 
   2.2.2 :050 > object.attribute.nil?
    => true
   ```
2. **empty** value i.e "" an empty string with **no spaces**

   ```
   2.2.2 :053 > object.attribute
    => "" 
   2.2.2 :054 > object.attribute.nil?
    => false
   ```
3. **empty** string **with spaces** " ".

   ```
   2.2.2 :057 > object.attribute
    => " " 
   2.2.2 :058 > object.attribute.nil?
    => false
   ```
4. value present in database i.e a **non-empty string**.

   ```
   2.2.2 :061 > object.attribute
    => "some value" 
   2.2.2 :062 > object.attribute.nil?
    => false
   ```

**Third Method:** `.blank?`

1. **nil** value i.e "nil" stored in the database

   ```
   2.2.2 :065 > object.attribute
    => nil 
   2.2.2 :066 > object.attribute.blank?
    => true
   ```
2. **empty** value i.e "" an empty string with **no spaces**

   ```
   2.2.2 :069 > object.attribute
    => "" 
   2.2.2 :070 > object.attribute.blank?
    => true
   ```
3. **empty** string **with spaces** " ".

   ```
   2.2.2 :073 > object.attribute
    => " " 
   2.2.2 :074 > object.attribute.blank?
    => true
   ```
4. value present in database i.e a **non-empty string**.

   ```
   2.2.2 :075 > object.attribute
    => "some value" 
   2.2.2 :076 > object.attribute.blank?
    => false
   ```

**Fourth Method:** `.present?`

1. **nil** value i.e "nil" stored in the database

   ```
   2.2.2 :088 > object.attribute
    => nil 
   2.2.2 :089 > object.attribute.present?
    => false
   ```
2. **empty** value i.e "" an empty string with **no spaces**

   ```
   2.2.2 :092 > object.attribute
    => "" 
   2.2.2 :093 > object.attribute.present?
    => false
   ```
3. **empty** string **with spaces** " ".

   ```
   2.2.2 :096 > object.attribute
    => " " 
   2.2.2 :097 > object.attribute.present?
    => false
   ```
4. value present in database i.e a **non-empty string**.

   ```
   2.2.2 :100 > object.attribute
    => "some value" 
   2.2.2 :101 > object.attribute.present?
    => true
   ```

You can use either of the four depending upon the situation you face.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

```
if !agent.cell.blank?
```

It works.

Comment: You might consider "unless agent.cell.blank?", which some assert is "more Ruby-ish"

Comment: I use unless unless agent.cell.blank because double negatives are awesome.

Comment: You can also use
    `if agent.cell.present?`

#present? returns the opposite of #blank?

Answer (score 1):

agent.cell? seems to work the same as agent.cell.blank? in RoR.

Comment: It does not seem to in rails 3.2.6 (or ruby 1.9)

Answer (score 0):

```
<% @broker.agents.each do |agent| %>
  ...
  <% unless agent.cell.empty? %>
    <span class="cell-number">Cell: <%= agent.cell %></span>
  <% end %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

I find the use of #each, `unless`, and `cell.empty?` to be more readable and easier to understand at first glance.

Answer (score 0):

you can actually check if the column contains nothing by doing
`Model.column == ""` will return true if the column type is string