# Check for value presence of multiple attributes in a activerecord object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a rails model object where i am checking for presence of whether some select attribute values are present or not.

For example lets say person model has fname, lname, age attributes.How can i check for the presence of fname, lname alone not being blank or null, For instance i know that we can do something like `person.fname.present? && person.lname.present?` but is there a more concise and ruby-friendly way to do the same?

Comment: Looks fine. See this answer for some additional details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39212101/11509906

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add any attribute you want to check as argument of values_at function.

```
person.attributes.values_at(:fname, :lname).all?(&:present?)
```

Comment: Side note: if you're checking the presence of booleans, you'll need to use `.all? { |attr| !attr.nil? }` as `false.present?` is `false`